# Does cruisecontrol.net run the publishers section if you abort the build?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

If a build is running and you go to the dashboard and abort it, does the publishers section still run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yep it is still ran

That's the idea of publishers, to publish the result of a build :-)
build ok, build broken or build aborted.

Comment: How would you determine the build was aborted in say a Nant target that's called from the publishers? Would CCNetIntegrationStatus have it?

Comment: Thanks by the way and CCNET is a great tool!

Comment: I think integration status has it, but there is a order you need to respect :
first the file merge publisher, next the xmlLogger, and than any other publisher or task. This should update the integration status correctly into the publisher section.

Comment: I see thanks. We ended up figuring out if the build was aborted by checking if an xml file was edited at the end of the tasks section. If it wasn't then we know the build was aborted.